# How can I resize my Filesystem Root partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, root

I want to resize the partition that is mounted at my filesystem root, because I am running out of space and trying to clean it out didn't give me much more space to work with.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   487M  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  18,6G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0 204,5G  0 part /home
```

This is what my disk looks like at the moment. So I would like to increase the space of sda5 using some space of my sda6 which has free space.

Unfortunately when I try to resize sda6 to make it smaller using Disks, it shows me:

> "Error unmounting filesystem"  "Error unmounting /dev/sda6: target is
> busy (udisks-error-quark, 14)

/dev/sda6 is "Mounted at /home"

How can I still resize my sda5 to make it have more space?

Comment: You could also find out *why* you are running out of space, and address that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a bootable USB disk and put GParted on it. Then boot from the USB, and you should have free access to your disk and its partitions. Of course, as always, make sure you have backups of your data: GParted is a powerful tool, but it can also create havoc if used carelessly. Good luck with the job :)